# npm ERR! ERROR: connect ETIMEDOUT 2606:4700::6810:1d22:80 when create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, npm

Im trying to create a react app using
`npx create-react-app my-app`
but im getting this error in prompt

```
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 2606:4700::6810:1a22:443
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-07T18_45_41_230Z-debug-0.log
```

I already deactivate proxy config and firewall in my pc, remove the npm proxy settings and set the registry in .npmrc with

```
npm config set proxy null
npm config set https-proxy null
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Im using a home network, im not using proxys.

It use to work few weeks ago. I'm not understanding what is happening.

Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the registry url from http to https like below , also cleaned the cache, removed the proxy but nothing work.

npm config get registry http://registry.npmjs.org

The only things that work for me is disabling ipv6 connectivity by going to the control panel

Video Reference =>  https://youtu.be/vzORm7AUUSQ